# passing in arguments to a restful controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have just started implenting restful controllers in laravel 4. I do not understand how to pass parameters to the functions in my controllers when using this way of routing.

Controller:

```
class McController extends BaseController
{
            private $userColumns = array("stuff here");

    public function getIndex()
    {
            $apps = Apps::getAllApps()->get();
            $apps=$apps->toArray();
            return View::make('mc')->nest('table', 'mc_child.table',array('apps'=>$apps, 'columns'=>$this->userColumns));
    }

    public function getTable($table)
    {
            $data = $table::getAll()->get();
            $data=$data->toArray();
            return View::make('mc')->nest('table', 'mc_child.table',array('apps'=>$apps, 'columns'=>$this->userColumns));
    }

}
```

route:

```
 Route::controller('mc', 'McController');
```

I am able to reach both URLs so my routing is working. How do I pass arguments to this controller when using this method of routing and controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a restful controller in Laravel, you can access the actions throgh the URI, e.g. with `Route::controller('mc', 'McController')` will match with routes `mc/{any?}/{any?}` etc. For your function `getTable`, you can access with the route `mc/table/mytable` where `mytable` is the parameter for the function.

**EDIT**
You must enable restful feature as follow:

```
class McController extends BaseController
{
    // RESTFUL
    protected static $restful = true;

    public function getIndex()
    {
        echo "Im the index";
    }

    public function getTable($table)
    {
        echo "Im the action getTable with the parameter ".$table;
    }
}
```

With that example, when I go to the route `mc/table/hi` I get the output: `Im the action getTable with the parameter hi`.

Comment: I can access the rout with mc/table. the get is what lets laravel know to call it for the action get, Therefore making it restful. when i pass another string into the url ex. mc/table/mytable it looks for 'mytable' as a function in the controller. that is the issue I am having. I would like to know if it is even possible to pass arguments to the controller using this way of routing.

Comment: This looks like you are using laravel 3. there may be some difference for laravel 4.

Comment: No. That example was made with Laravel 4 and I think there is not much difference in L3. It's weird you can pass parameters. Maybe trying a new installation of L4.

Comment: I do not have `protected static $restful = true;` in my code I thought that this was not necessary in laravel 4.

Comment: ahhh I guess it ended up being the code in my function! it is working now. thank you!

Comment: if i want o pass the parameter in `getIndex()` than it would work? i tried with that and not able to access my parameter `mc/index/myarg1/` worked but `mc/myarg1/` is not , please suggest